# .bin file to .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a file (.bin) which contains SRAM data (containing hex characters). I need it to convert it to a .txt file.

Any suggestions please on how it can be done in MATLAB?

Thanks!

BR,
\Kashif

Comment: Its solved now.                                                      fid = fopen('name_of_file.bin','rb');
M = fread(fid,inf,'uint8','ieee-be');
M=dec2bin(char(M),8192);

Comment: You can answer your own question.